# Message Identifier in Protobug Message

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Is there a way to get something like an ID for a protobuf message.

E.g. I have:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package protobuf;

message parameters_t
{
    string audio_device = 1;
}

message master_t
{
    enum type_t
    {
        unknown = 0;
        login_rsp = 1;
    }

    type_t type = 1;
}
```

What I want to do in C++ is send the size over the wire, then some ID of the message and the the buffer.

E.g. `paramters_t` is ID 0 (statically accessible) and `master_t` is ID 1, so I can do in my code:

```
if (id == protobuf::master_t::id) {
    ...
}
else if (id == protobuf::paramters_t::id) {
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this without manually assigning the values? I want that to be set in the protofile somehow. It can be a constant I define myself, i dont care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done to solve this now is this (arguably not very elegant) solution of putting an enum in every message like this:

```
enum pt
{
    invalid = 0;
    packet_type = 3;
}
```

This enum is in every message, but with another value for `packet_type`. It looks like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package protobuf;

message parameters_t
{
    enum pt
    {
        invalid = 0;
        packet_type = 1;
    }
    string audio_device = 1;
}

message login_message_t
{
    enum pt
    {
        invalid = 0;
        packet_type = 2;
    }

    enum process_type_t
    {
        invalid_process = 0;
        player = 1;
        display = 2;
    }

    process_type_t process_type = 1;
    uint32 player_id = 2;
}

message generic_message_t
{
    enum pt
    {
        invalid = 0;
        packet_type = 3;
    }
    enum type_t
    {
        unknown = 0;
        login_done = 1;
        audio_init_success = 2;
    }

    type_t type = 1;
}

message error_message_t
{
    enum pt
    {
        invalid = 0;
        packet_type = 4;
    }

    enum error_t
    {
        unknown = 0;
        could_not_init = 1;
        could_not_open_audio_device = 2;
    }

    error_t error = 1;
    bool critical = 2;
}
```

The advantage of this is that I can use it in templates for a class that automatically detects the packet type and identifies it to give it to a registered handler, as it can be accessed via `protobuf::error_message_t::packet_type` to get the value.

Comment: There is very similar to a GOF pattern? It's very similar to 'chain of responsability'

Answer (score 1):

A typical way is to just define an enum:

```
enum MsgId {
  MSGID_MASTER = 0;
  MSGID_PARAMETERS = 1;
}
```

You can then access them in C++ like constants.

Comment: Thank you, ive done it in a pretty similar way, but with my way you can use it in templates.